# No Subtle Essence or Fallen Tooth in the Gold Auction House

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm searching for Subtle Essence at the Gold Auction House, but nobody sells it (or that's what it looks like). Then I tried selling it myself but nobody buys it, I can't even find my own sale.

Why is this happening? Is it forbidden by Blizzard? Is it not profitable?

Ps. I have an EU account, and I have not charged money into my battle.net account yet.

Comment: Probably a temporary hiccup, is my guess.

Comment: It's been like this for 1 day at least, since I first checked the auction house

Comment: For more info, I have an EU account, my level is actually 14 with my first character

Comment: Can you find your own sales for other items?  If not, this should be a bug report to Blizzard.

Comment: @MatthewRead for an amulet I can see my own sale. Anyway, I can't believe nobody sells this two materials at the action house, there has to be something happening!

Comment: I have the same issue. Getting the "No one is selling this item at this time"-message. I tried listing 100 subtle essences up for sale for 2 gp each (below the price for which they can be sold to npcs) and i still says no one is selling. And they are not getting sold. So I think this is a bug. Btw, I am also on the EU gold auction house.

Comment: Thanks god, I'm not alone! It may be problem in EU gold..

Comment: I just placed the ticket, the support team is investigating the issue, I'll post the answer asap.

Comment: It's appearing after applying patch 1.03. Still, there are some other bugs...

Comment: I think this was just a temporary issue. The commodity auctions seem to be working for me now.

Comment: @Alderath still I cannot check gold price or gems price in real money auction house, but the other issue has been fixed with the update 1.03 or 1.03b I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely a bug with the commodities market, try searching for other commodities(gems, pages, tomes, plans and other trading goods). If they all turn op as nothing posted it is most likely a temporary bug. For more information go to the [official Technical Support forum](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/4436696/).

Comment: gems, tomes, match a search, but normal materials don't

Comment: So it looks like it was an EU server issue and not a personal bug ;)

Comment: @Nacho for me, some gems do not show up. I can see chipped --> flawless rubies, but no one appears to be selling perfect rubies. My bet is that this is because of the same underlying cause as the essences.

Answer (score 2):

Nacho, I ran some tests and chances are, you were in the Real Money Auction House instead of the Gold Auction House.

Here is a **screenshot of me searching for Subtle Essence** at the Gold Auction House.
[image: SE]

Now, here is a **screenshot of me searching for Fallen Tooth** at the Gold Auction House.
[image: FT]

As you can see, both of these searches showed the items. So **Blizzard did not forbid it due to how non-profitable it is.**

Next, I'm going to see if I can see my auctions for these items after putting it on sale at the **Gold Auction House**. Below, you can see that they do show up.

[image: OnSale]

Finally, I'm going to switch to the **Real Money Auction House** to see if **Fallen Tooth** and **Subtle Essence** show up.

[image: RMAH1]
[image: RMAH2]

So hopefully you were just searching for those items in the wrong place. If you were in the **Gold Auction House**, then I would have to do some additional research to see what is wrong.

**TL;DR Switch to the Gold Auction House.**

Comment: I was in the **Gold Auction House**. I can't check the Real Money Auction House, as I have no money in my battle.net account yet.

Comment: I'm updating it...

Comment: Wow, someone is really not liking my answers today. Been downvoted on all my latest answers.. :(

Comment: not me, i appreciate your help

Comment: @Nacho if that's the case, then my best advice at this point is to just send a report to Blizzard, unless anyone else has experienced this also and is willing to share a fix.

Comment: I'll try asking there

Comment: @Hunger It could be because you are making an assumption on what the problem might be, and working from there.  For troubleshooting, it's usually a good idea to start with the assumption that the user knows what they're doing.

Comment: @fbueckert ... no.  Have you ever done tech support?  Even smart people fail to notice or try the obvious all the time, and most common problems are simple, so that's where you start ("Have you tried rebooting?" etc.).

Comment: @MatthewRead I've done plenty of tech support.  I find I get a much better response if I assume my customers aren't incompetent.  Regardless, assuming you know what the problem is and ignoring user information isn't the way to go about it.

Comment: any help is appreciated, doesn't matter if it comes from the thinking that user has any idea or not. By the way, @fbueckert, Matthew didn't ignore the info. I updated it after his answer.

Comment: @MatthewRead I know the first thing many tech support representatives do is start with the basics. My best friend has been saying this for years working in a as tech support for a major cell phone carrier, "Have you tried taking the battery out of your phone?" And more often than not, that fixes the problem. Stating that "if you were using the RMAH, that could be your problems" would still be a useful answer to some people having a similar issue, even if that is not the case for the OP.  Thanks Matthew Read though, b/c I did not know that.

Comment: @fbueckert Stupid mistakes ≠ incompetence.

Comment: just placed a ticket, they said it might be a bug, and they're investigating... I'll post the answer